# change time format in SQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

metabase in .cvs export show time in this format:
`2017-08-30T02:15:30.000+04:30`
but when I export data directly with mysql returns:
`2017-08-30 02:15:30`
how can change this format in SELECT?

Comment: Refer this - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @byteUI . . . You should close/delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I find it. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp 
thanks.
127 yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ    ISO8601 (with time zone Z)